# I got a conflicting files error message from pacman

Tags: python, linux, archlinux, arch, pacman-package-manager

failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/**init**.py exists in both 'python-lsassy' and 'python-dsinternals'
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-311.opt-1.pyc exists in both 'python-lsassy' and 'python-dsinternals'
/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-311.pyc exists in both 'python-lsassy' and 'python-dsinternals'
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.

I just installed a fresh version of blackarch linux  to see what its all about, but when I did pacman -Syu this happened. I have tried deleting the conflicting files but i think I am missing something because the same exact error happens. This is my first time trying arch as i am used to ubuntu and debian. Can anyone help?

I tried
pacman -Qo /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/**init**.py
it told me that it does not belong to any package
then I tried
rm -rf /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tests/**init**.py
and reran but it had the exact same error.

Comment: That would be a question for e.g. superuser.com instead, because it's not about software developent but rather about system administration.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. You dont remove the files with rm -rf you use pacman -R oops.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not being able to install a package because that package had a lost dependency, it was not owned by anything. When I looked up python-pygments and saw how many other programs depend/use it, I didn't want it gone ether. For me, the solution was to overwrite and repair python-pigments, getting rid of pygmentize's ownerless problem Error found /usr/bin/pygmentize. This fixed it for me.

<sudo pacman -S python-pygments --overwrite /usr/bin/pygmentize>

Fill in the application and path to fit your needs.

I hope that helps someone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).